# How do I get mysql to start for the first time?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, linux

I want to get mysql to start for the first time.  I installed it on RHEL version 6.  All of the commands posted were executed as root.

As a test, I ran this:

```
# yum install mysql
```

This is the output:

> Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos Package
>   1:mariadb-5.5.47-1.el7_2.x86_64 already installed and latest version
>   Nothing to do

The directory /etc/init.d/ has no mysql or mariadb file inside it.

I tried these five commands (and posted the output after them):

```
# service mysql start
```

> Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  mysql.service Failed to start
>   mysql.service: Unit mysql.service failed to load: No such file or
>   directory.

```
# systemctl start mysql.service
```

> Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service failed to load: No
>   such file or directory.

```
# systemctl start mysql.service
```

> Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service failed to load: No
>   such file or directory.

```
# systemctl start mariadb
```

> Failed to start mariadb.service: Unit mariadb.service failed to load:
>   No such file or directory.

```
# systemctl start mysql
```

> Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service failed to load: No
>   such file or directory.

I used

> whereis mysql

The resulting outputs gave me no leads of files to start to get the service to start.

What should I do to get MySQL running?

Comment: When the service fails to start you need to locate the error log and check it for details.

Answer (score 1):

To setup mysql database server, follow step by step of below given URL

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-install-mysql-under-rhel/